# Runtime error 1004 when deleting multiple columns in excel VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

Getting the runtime error 1004 when running the following macro that has columns ranging from A to BJ.

```
Sub sbVBS_To_Delete_Specific_Multiple_Columns()
Sheets("GRT Flight Data Log_raw").Range("A:B,H:I,K:L,P,AB:AH,AK:AN,AQ,AT,AZ:BJ").EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub
```

I have used this code on the same data log deleting different columns for a different application and it works just fine. This is the code that works:

```
Sub sbVBS_To_Delete_Specific_Multiple_Columns()

Sheets("GRT Flight Data Log").Range("A:B,H:L,P:Q,S:BJ").EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub
```

I have exhausted every possibility I have found, please help.

Comment: Not sure about your problem. But is "P" a range? Maybe you need to do "P:P"

Comment: You are right my ranges had single column set so I changed all single column values to reflect that i.e. AQ is now AQ:AQ and P is now P:P like you said thanks.

Comment: "runtime error 1004" is all the error says? It should say something more detailed.

Comment: It did say more about ranges but you solved it regardless so thanks.

Comment: Oh, you edited that comment. Thought you weren't helped. I'll write my comment as answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that in ranges you have `P` which is not a range but a single letter.

You should change that to something like `P:P`